# Windows Explorer freezing, narrowed it down to a certain DLL

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, freeze

I've had a problem for a while now.
Whenever I hold ctrl or shift to select multiple files, my entire PC freezes.
After a while, I narrowed it down to a single thread in windows explorer causing this issue.
When I killed the thread, the issue ceased.

Here's a thread overview from process explorer:

**Normal**:

[image: Thread tab of process explorer]

**While holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>**:

[image: Thread tab of process explorer while holding Ctrl or Shift]

CPU usage tops at about 31 percent.
I looked into the DLL, lanenpat.dll,
and found it was located in C:\Windows\favipsql.
Here's a screenshot of the folder:

[image: C:\Windows\favipsql directory]

I'm beginning to suspect it's bloatware, but I'm afraid to delete it for fear of royally f**king something up.
Help?

UPDATE:
I opened the DLL in notepad++, and found this at line 11337:

```
JX9 VM Dump   Copyright (C) 2012-2013 Symisc Systems
                              http://jx9.symisc.net/
====================================================
```

As it turns out, jx9 is "an embeddable scripting engine that implements a Turing complete programming language based on JSON."

UPDATE 2:
Another text chunk at line 18589:

```
Copyright (c) 1992-2004 by P.J. Plauger, licensed by Dinkumware, Ltd. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
```

Dinkumware is a supplier of C and C++ libraries. So, I haven't really found anything. I'll proceed to check the rest of the files in the directory.

Comment: These do *not* seem like default Windows MS files. "Symisc Systems S.U.A.R.L, is a Tunisian startup that develops embedded and standalone software for the IT community." Have you added any software from them? If not, have you performed a thorough scan for malware, including adware?

Comment: I scanned it with MSE, but came up with nothing. Do you have any adware removal softare to recommend?

Comment: Kaspersky Free Virus Scan might be worth a try. Avast! Free has a browser extension checker. For that matter, open IE, select *Tools | Manage add-ons*, and disable any of which your unsure. IE was tied to Windows Explorer, and there might still be interaction in Windows 7. BTW, Plauger is a well-known author and developer in C/C++; the issue could have resulted from a user-made app for a C++ course.

Comment: If you look at the picture of the folder, you'll see dxibart.dll. I took a look at it with lockhunter, and apparently a ton of programs are using it. http://i.imgur.com/UM0zugh.png

Comment: It maybe one of the libraries for faviSQL

Answer (score 0):

FINAL UPDATE, FOR NOW

A safe mode boot and deletion of lanenpat.dll seems to have fixed it, for now.
I'm running sfc as I type this to see if I messed up something, and will update if something else went wrong.